# Connecting to a SSL enabled Kafka broker to consume message using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka

I am trying to connect to a SSL enabled Kafka broker to consume message using pyspark

My code is as follows:

```py
import os
import sys
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_112"
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.0.2 pyspark-shell'

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
import json

sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonSparkStreamingKafka_RM_01")
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 60)

kafkaParams = { "bootstrap.servers": "<valid kafka brokers>", "group.id": "myConsumer_group", "auto.offset.reset": "largest", "enable.auto.commit": "false", "security.protocol": "ssl", "ssl.truststore.location": "/opt/mount1/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/cert/price_kfk_truststore.jks", "ssl.truststore.password": "1wbmz", "ssl.keystore.location": "/opt/mount1/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/cert/price_kfk_keystore.jks", "ssl.keystore.password": "pwd1", "ssl.key.password": "pwd1"}
topic="MyTopic"
stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], kafkaParams)
```

When I run this code , I get below Warning and not able to consume message:

```py
WARN VerifiableProperties: Property enable.auto.commit is not valid
WARN VerifiableProperties: Property security.protocol is not valid
WARN VerifiableProperties: Property ssl.key.password is not valid
WARN VerifiableProperties: Property ssl.keystore.location is not valid
WARN VerifiableProperties: Property ssl.keystore.password is not valid
WARN VerifiableProperties: Property ssl.truststore.location is not valid
WARN VerifiableProperties: Property ssl.truststore.password is not valid
```

How to fix this issue? Please help.